# Make the following equality true by putting brackets

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

> Make the following equality true by putting brackets somewhere:
> $$720 - 80 : 20 + 20 = 30$$
> ":" stands for the ordinary division. Also, we cannot put brackets between the digits of a whole number.

This is given in a book for primary school pupils. I've been trying for about 10-15 minutes but no any result. I'm starting to doubt if it is really possible to do what is required.

The following options were the most likely in my opinion:
$$(720 - 80) : 20 + 20 = 32 + 20 \neq 30 \\
(720 - 80) : (20 + 20) = 640 : 40 = 16 \neq 30$$
But, no, they do not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you state what are the things you're been trying, even if it doesn't yield a correct answer? E.g. There are finitely many places to put (), so how many have you tried?

Comment: There are exactly five ways to bracket the left-hand side, and none of them seem to work.

Comment: $720\div(4+20)=30$

Comment: Can you clarify what $:$ is? I'm guessing from context that it refers to division, but that's not a common usage.

Comment: @GregMartin There are several more than that, esp if you allow brackets in between the digit (which isn't made clear here).

Comment: 1) Thanks for adding your work. 2) Can you clarify if you're allowed to add multiple brackets as per your 2nd line? (It might be phrasing in the textbook, as I assume most would only allow 1 pair)

Comment: @CalvinLin There is no limit on the number of brackets since the book does not say anything about it.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner You mean ($- \mapsto  \div$)? But that is not allowed, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you verify that the first sign is indeed $ -$? If yes, I agree there is (very likely) no solution.

Comment: $(720 - 80 : 20 + 2)0 = (3)0$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner OP clarified that you can't put brackets within the digits. That was my first approach.

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes, the sign is indeed $-$.

Comment: If there is a typo in the book, then I will be just taking your time for nothing. Anyway, thank you very much for your thoughts!

Comment: Doesn't seem to be possible.  You must divide *something* but 20 or 40 and if you *don't* divide 720 by 20 or 40 you get $720 - something\ not\ that\ big$ so you have to do $(720-80):something$  or $640:something$. And $640$ is either $32\times 20$ or $16\times 40$ (or $8\times 80$???)  But our only options for the $something$ is $20$ or $(20+20)=40$.  Neither of which work.  It seems close as $(720-80):2 - 20$ or $(720-80):20-2$ work or $720 \div (80:20+20)$ works, I suspect this either has a typo or the constructor made an error s/he didn't catch.